# Should we burninate the tag [same]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The tag [same](/questions/tagged/same) is mostly used to express a word [*same* (AKA *similar*)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/same). No tag wiki, it is used with different tags (language). And it doesn't add any value IMO.

Should this tag be burninated?

Comment: I did a random spot-check on 4 pages of the tag and couldn't see anything approaching a legitimate use either. Looks prime for burninating.

Comment: [I'm just going to leave this here.](http://stackapps.com/questions/4207/burninator-toolkit)

Comment: Gone in ten minutes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. The [same](/questions/tagged/same) tag should be burninated.

In reviewing a good number of the 178 currently tagged questions, I don't see any purpose served by the tag at all. It appears to be generally slapped on by people trying to fill out the maximum number of tags possible and is usually a keyword from the title of the question. The trouble is it doesn't seem to add any useful categorization to questions. The tag is not something any expert in any specific field would use to find related questions. The only thing that ties these questions together is their use of the word "same" even when the context varies widely.