# Should we burninate the tag [similar] same as [same]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The tag [similar](/questions/tagged/similar) is mostly used to express a word [*same*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/same). No tag wiki, it is used with different tags (language). And it doesn't add any value IMO.

Should this tag be burninated similar to [same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188205/187824)?

Comment: There are too many puns here, and you've already used some of them ;)

Comment: Similar is not the same as same, just similar.

Comment: I've manually killed [similarily] which was a typo of [similarity] used on 3 questions. [similarity] itself is probably a good synonym target for [similar] if anyone thinks they're worth keeping.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I don't know what you guys are talking about.  There are no questions tagged [similar].  You should probably just mark this as completed.

Comment: @Won't I don't know what you are talking about. This question is tagged as completed. ;)

Comment: Let me use a simile to explain the difference between `similar` and `same`. Similar is to same as same is to similar. Confused yet?

Comment: @Richard my mind's synonym function that relates same and similar words can't decide if similar is the same as same or if same is similar to similar.